# how pass data fetched from server to intent in android?

Tags: android, json, android-intent

I have to pass data fetched from server to ACTION_DIAL intent. So how could I pass that data to the intent?

Below is my adapter class code:

`intent.putExtra,("datafromserver", dataFromS);`

How can I handle the fetched from the server and pass this data to the intent?

Comment: You didn't add any code. Please add it so we can actually help you.

Comment: Like this: `intent.putExtra,("datafromserver", dataFromServer);`.

Comment: Please provide your code in question

Answer (score 3):

The place where the mobile number is where your received phone number from JSON should be,

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL, Uri.fromParts("tel", "+91 1166008855", null));
            startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: bro i have to pass data from server not local data

Comment: Can you please elaborate what are you trying to achieve so that we can help you with a possible solution?

Comment: i have fetched data from server in recyclerview and i have call button and on pressing call button i have to call intent action dial

Comment: Adapter snippet:public void onBindViewHolder(final MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
        final Contact contact = contactListFiltered.get(position);
        holder.name.setText(contact.getName());
        holder.address.setText(contact.getAddress());



        Glide.with(context)
                .load(contact.getImage())
                .apply(RequestOptions.circleCropTransform())
                .into(holder.thumbnail);



    }

Comment: Try Vish's answer. His approach is correct. You need to fetch the phone number from the view, on click of the recyclerview, and then use the intent, as described by vish, to make the phone call intent

Comment: data is receiving in arraylist so how to pass that data

Comment: atish sir can i get ur whatsapp no so we can discuss there

Comment: Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL, Uri.fromParts("tel", contact.getPhoneNumber(), null));
            startActivity(intent); //you will have something like getPhoneNumber() in Contacts